# Writing a story in Japanese: how to handle dialogue

Tags: grammar, syntax

I'm an elementary Japanese student. I am trying to write a simple story in Japanese, and I want to make it as interesting as possible with my current knowledge of the language. I am concerned about the dialogue in my story. The only way I know how to write that someone said something is through the use of という. I am worried that my story will become repetitive during a scene with a lot of dialogue. I don't want it to sound like this:

> スーさんが「さむいです。」といいました。
>
> はなこさんが「そうですね。」といいました。
>
> スーさんが「かえりましょう。」といいました。
>
> はなこさんが「ちょっとまってください。とりをみたいです。」といいました。

I will be reading this story aloud to an audience, so I want to avoid the repetitive "[person] が [dialogue] といいました" construction. What are some ways I can spice up my dialogue? Can it work the same way in English, where I can remove the dialogue tag (he said, she said) when my speakers are established? Can I also mix in action between the dialogue while doing this?

> スーさんが「さむいです。」といいました。
>
> はなこさんが「そうですね。」といいました。
>
> スーさんがはなこさんのてをつかみました。「かえりましょう。」
>
> 「ちょっとまってください。とりをみたいです。」
>
> "It's cold," said Sue.
>
> "It is," said Hanako.
>
> Sue grasped Hanako's hand. "Let's go home."
>
> "Wait a bit. I want to watch the birds."

I know my dialogue is going to sound awkward and unnatural, but I'm not worried about that since I'm not at the point where I can pick up on nuances. Right now I am worried about getting the grammar down and not sounding repetitive.

Any help is appreciated! (Also, please answer in kana or romaji.)

Comment: The dialogue itself sounds sort of stilted ...

Comment: Yes, I know. I won't be able to make natural-sounding dialogue at this point, but that's not my concern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can it work the same way in English, where I can remove the dialogue tag (he said, she said) when my speakers are established? Can I also mix in action between the dialogue while doing this?

Yes.

> スーさんがはなこさんのてをつかみました。「かえりましょう。」
>   「ちょっとまってください。とりをみたいです。」

It looks good to me.

To sound less repetitive and more natural (and colorful?) I think you could also...

- use other verbs like つぶやく、はなしかける、きく、こたえる etc.
- place the subject and the verb phrase before or after the dialogue
- leave out the quotative marker と (though not always possible)
- use the present tense (to sound vivid or lively)

For example...

> スーさんが「さむいわ。」といいました。
>   「そうね。」（と）はなこさんがこたえます。

---

- use 「verb+と」 form (meaning "When~~"), or a conjunction like すると
- you could even leave out the verb phrase (using 体言止め)

> 「さむいわ。」スーさんがささやくと、
>   「そうね。」と、はなこさん。

---

- use a relative clause
- you could even use a totally different verb than いう、きく、こたえる etc.

> 「さむいわ。」とふるえるスーさんに、
>   はなこさんが「そうね。」とちいさくうなずきます。
>   「かえりましょ。」と（いいながら）、スーさんははなこさんのてをつかみました。

---

- you could also use 体言止め with a relative clause:

> 「そうね。」とうなずくはなこさん。

---

- or you could even go like this:

> XXにやってきたスーさんとはなこさん。しばらくすると、スーさんがこごえでつぶやきます。
>   「さむいわ。」
>   「そうね。」
>   「かえりましょ。」
>   「ちょっとまって。とりがみたいの。」

---

I think there would be several more ways but this is all I can think of right now...

Good luck :)